# Concatenate layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

If I am concatenating 2 conv2D layers by using Concatenate function in keras then it will concatenate the weights associated with each layer or output of that layer?

to more generalize my doubt,

`layer1 = conv2D()

layer2 = conv2D()
result = Concatenate([layer1, layer2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will concatenate the results of the weights after activation functions applied upon those weights.

Otherwise, it would render useless any activation function which is applied on `layer`(from 1 to N for example), where `layer` has an activation function.

Imagine in ResNet(residual networks) or other layer connections which use Add/Multiply/Subtract/Concatenate operations.

The output results are those after applying the necessary transformations(either add/multiply/subtract/concatenate etc.)